# CSS Speech balloon width

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I believe this is a pretty basic question for someone who knows CSS language (not my case lol). I'm using [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/mek5Z/) hosted at jsfiddle to make some speech balloons in my website. The problem came when the message inside the balloon is little. For example, in the code posted above, change the code from "bubble you" balloon to something like:

```
<div class="bubble you">Hi.</div>
```

You will see that the balloon stay on the same horizontal line as the previous balloon, and this is ugly and strange. I want the balloons to stay one after another (one below another) even when the message is small like a simple 'Hi'... What properties should I change or add in the balloons classes to get this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `clear: both` to `.bubble`.

Demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/mek5Z/1957/

```
.bubble{
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    clear: both
}
```